# Remove ?locale=en from a url

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop

I'm having this problem with Prestashop CMS.
There is only English language but I really don't know how to remove this tag, it is really disturbing because the page loads twice: first time for url.com, second time for url.com/?locale=en.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the non-necessary languages in localization -> languages?

Regards